# List take time to insert data from database

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have list of class which class has 3 properties like this.

```
public string attributeName { get; set; }
public string strFormId { get; set; }
public string strValue { get; set; }
```

I am adding my database data into it through list like this

```
List<myAttributeData> attributesData = new List<myAttributeData>();
var result = db.ExecuteQuery<myAttributeData>(query, new object[0]);

// attributesData.Clear();
foreach (myAttributeData item in result.ToList())
{
    if (item.attributeName == "Province ")
    {
        var Loc = from d in db.tblLocations 
                  where d.LocationId == Convert.ToInt32(item.strValue)
                  select new
                  {
                       d.LocationName
                  };
        foreach (var item1 in Loc.ToList())
        {
            attributesData.Add(new myAttributeData()
            {
                attributeName = item.attributeName,
                strFormId = item.strFormId,
                strValue = item1.LocationName
            });
         }
     }
```

The problem is its taking so much time right now i have 70 thousands record into my database table which is take more than half hour any suggestion about this situation thanks. I have to add my data into list because I need it to use it back when it is needed can anybody give me solutions to cut the time of adding data into string.

Comment: I am just trying to understand what you are doing.  I see your getting your collection of object attributesData called result.  Then you are getting the location name from the location table by the location ID.   It just doesn't seem like even your object and query are set up right. Hmm now why don't you just put another property in your attributesData object called locationName.  Rewrite your query so that it also includes the locationName?  I would of made it made it locID and made it an integer instead of strValue and a string.  I would also save the  locID in the DB not the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word: caching.

The problem with this code is that you're iterating through your 70,000 records, and for each one, you're going back to the database, to read in extra information.

```
foreach (myAttributeData item in result.ToList())
{
    if (item.attributeName == "Province ")
    {
        var Loc = from d in db.tblLocations  
        where d.LocationId == Convert.ToInt32(item.strValue)
```

You'll find your code flies if you can cache the list of locations (before calling your `foreach` loop)

```
List<Location> cachedLocations = db.tblLocations.ToList();
```

..and then set your `Loc` variable from there:

```
var Loc = from d in cachedLocations  
where d.LocationId == Convert.ToInt32(item.strValue)
```

Always keep the number of calls back to the database as low as possible.

Good luck!